# I want to make sure that code is really implement the steepest descent method

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I made that code for steepest descent and I want to know if i on the wright way ?!! and when I put x1=0 and x2=0 it doesn't work because of diff function !!

```
Max_iter=5;

n=0;

lamda=0;

syms x1

syms x2

x=[x1;x2];

fun=inline(x1-x2+2*x1^2+2*x1*x2+2*x2^2);

diff(fun(x1,x2),x1)

 gradf=[diff(fun(x1,x2),x1);diff(fun(x1,x2),x2)];

while   n<=Max_iter

    if(gradf~=0)

     gradf=[diff(fun(x1,x2),x1);diff(fun(x1,x2),x2)]; 

     y=x-lamda*gradf;

     x=y;
     n=n+1;

    end

end

n ; 

x;
```

Comment: Nothing will happen if `lamda` is 0.

Comment: I want to make it's initial value = 0 @Nitish

Comment: @TaghreedMohamed - Then set `x1` and `x2` to 0, not `lambda`.  `lambda` is your learning rate, and setting it to 0 means that the solution will not change from its initial value.  It will simply stay put and not "learn" anything.

Comment: when I make X1 and X2 =0 I got an error because diff function !!! @rayryeng

Comment: You seem to mistake me for a mind reader or clairvoyant.  Perhaps you can share what this error is to minimize and prevent any future frustration of our discussion henceforth.

Comment: Your code has several problems with it which throw errors. 1. [`inline`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html?searchHighlight=inline) takes a string as an argument. You provide it with a scalar value. It would probably be simpler to use an [Anonymous Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) anyway.

Comment: 2. Your function `fun` returns a single value. [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html?searchHighlight=diff) takes a matrix or vector and returns the difference between adjacent elements. If you want the difference between `x1` and the output of your function use simple subtraction, i.e. `fun(x1, x2)-x1` or concatenate them in a vector and use `diff`, i.e. `diff([fun(x1, x2), x1])`

Comment: Aside from these problems, you also need to make sure that you start somewhere with a non-zero gradient. With your current code, if you start at `x1=0, x2=0`, the `gradf` will also be 0, which means your if condition will never be met and you'll be stuck endlessly in the while loop. Consider using a for loop instead.